# Which pro-Assad forces use crypto as funding?

Tags: military, syria, finance, cryptocurrency

Are there any Pro-Assad forces or militias that use cryptocurrencies to finance their battles?

During my research on the Ukrainian war there are people on both sides using crypto for financing of their operations.
Like [Rusich](https://www.itv.com/news/2023-06-05/neo-nazis-gaming-and-crypto-how-russias-war-is-financed-from-the-shadows) or [Azov](https://www.supportazov.com/en/support).

What I rather less heard of is the usage of crypto by the Assad forces in the Syrian civil war.

I wonder if there is at least one unit that use it to support their operations?

Comment: Any context or prior research?

Answer (score 3):

Hezbollah, a paramilitary group that provides training for pro-Assad paramilitary groups and has fought against rebel forces, with about 4000 fighters inside Syria [source](https://guides.library.illinois.edu/Syria/Pro-Assad) has used cryptocurrency to some extent, as its traditional sources of funding have been reduced (by sanctions against Iran, and by hyperinflation in Venezuela)  [source](https://scholarship.tricolib.brynmawr.edu/bitstream/handle/10066/21675/2019EaddyA.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)